# Need help to select and loop a table asp classic

Tags: asp-classic

I need some help in looping the right way. I'm missing something.

I have to select an order from a cart table and then mail a confirmation to the customer with the products and the sale company address from another table.

The problem is that the products in 1 order can come from 2 different companies so I need to first display the products from company 1 and then the address from company 1 and then the products from company 2 and then the address from company 2.

So it needs to look like this.

Product 1
Product 2

Company name 1
Address 1
Postcode 1
City 1

Product 3
Product 4

Company name 2
Address 2
Postcode 2
City 2

And this is what I have now.

```
sql = " SELECT * FROM cart WHERE ordernummer = "&ordernummer&" group by userId"
set rs = conn.Execute (sql)

do until rs.eof
            uId=rs("userId")
            sql7 = " SELECT * FROM cart WHERE userId = "&uId&""
            set rs7 = conn.Execute (sql7)
            do until rs7.eof
                art=art&"<br>"&rs7("artikel")&" "&rs7("pris")&" kr"
            rs7.movenext
            loop

sql3 = " SELECT * FROM users WHERE userId = "&uId&""
            set rs3 = conn.Execute (sql3)
            foretagsnamn=rs3("foretagsnamn")
            adress=rs3("adress")
            postnr=rs3("postnr")
            postadress=rs3("postadress")
            email=rs3("email")
            hamtatext=rs3("hamtatext")
            kartlank=rs3("kartaemaillink")

            companyinfo="<br><br>"&foretagsnamn&"<br>" &_ 
             adress&"<br>" &_ 
             postnr&"<br>" &_ 
             postadress&"<br>" &_ 
             "<a href=mailto:"&email&" style='text-decoration:none;color:#6d6d72;' target='_blank'>"&email&"</a><br>" &_
             "<a href="&kartlank&" target='_blank' style='text-decoration:none;color:#F90;'>Se karta</a><br>" &_ 
             "Du kan nu h&auml;mta dina varor: <span style='color:#F90;'>"& hamtatext &"</span><br><br>"

            companyinfo2=companyinfo2+companyinfo
            companyinfo=""
            art2=art2+art
            art = ""      
     rs.movenext
     loop



     message="<br>"&art2&companyinfo2
    response.write message&"<br>"
```

And the db looks like this.
Where userId is the different companies.

[image]

But with this, it displays all products and then the company 1 info only.
I have tested with so many different variants of this, but I can't get it right.
So any input really appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You're right you are missing a few things... A basic understanding of SQL queries *(grouping, joining etc.)*, how to correctly query data in Classic ASP without exposing the application to SQL Injection. Suggest you find a good beginner tutorial on website design using Classic ASP, unfortunately [so] isn't a good format for tutorials which it is clear you sorely need.

Comment: Yes Lankymart, I will adress the SQL injection, but not today. And yes, I´m not as good as you are, but that is not my question :-)

Comment: It's not meant as an insult believe me, just don't feel this is the right place to be asking these questions. You need to go away read a good tutorial or a good book to get a better understanding of basic concepts first. In fact if you are not maintaining existing websites I'd implore you to move to a newer technology like ASP.Net using concepts like MVC, ORM etc., rather than wasting your time learning an old technology which is slowly being replaced. For context Classic ASP is over 20+ years old now.

Comment: Well, I solved it, even if I can´t what you can, with no basic understanding and with an crappy technology ;-)

Comment: Glad you found a solution, feel free to post it if you think it will help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sql-command that will give all the information in one record-set and then you can just write each product line, and when the userid changes, THEN you write the previous companies address (which you have in variables as before).

```
sql="select * from cart c join users u on c.userID=u.userID where c.ordernummer = "&ordernummer&" group by c.userId"
```

The sql above JOINs the two tables together ON the column userID in both tables. the c and u behind the table namnes are just shorter names for those tables. You could use the full names aswell.

THEN, in the do until loop, you write down the company address information as you've done, and then you do a check on the first row in the do until loop you check if the rs.userID is different than the variable userID you have saved, if so, write the address. Also you need to write the address of the last company outside the loop after there are no more rows :)

Full code (using as much of your code as I could):

```
sql = " select * from cart c join users u on c.userID=u.userID where c.ordernummer = "&ordernummer&" group by c.userId"
set rs = conn.Execute (sql)
uId=0
do until rs.eof
    if uID<>rs("userId") and uID>0 then
        'This next row is a new company, Write the company information here, before getting new info and writing new rows.
        companyinfo="<br><br>"&foretagsnamn&"<br>" &_ 
         adress&"<br>" &_ 
         postnr&"<br>" &_ 
         postadress&"<br>" &_ 
         "<a href=mailto:"&email&" style='text-decoration:none;color:#6d6d72;' target='_blank'>"&email&"</a><br>" &_
         "<a href="&kartlank&" target='_blank' style='text-decoration:none;color:#F90;'>Se karta</a><br>" &_ 
         "Du kan nu h&auml;mta dina varor: <span style='color:#F90;'>"& hamtatext &"</span><br><br>"

        response.write companyinfo&"<br />"
    end if

    uId=rs("userId")
    foretagsnamn=rs("foretagsnamn")
    adress=rs("adress")
    postnr=rs("postnr")
    postadress=rs("postadress")
    email=rs("email")
    hamtatext=rs("hamtatext")
    kartlank=rs("kartaemaillink")
    'Do a response.write of this data here for each row below.                
    art=art&"<br>"&rs("artikel")&" "&rs("pris")&" kr"
    response.write art&"<br />"
    art = ""      
    rs.movenext
loop

'Remeber to write the last company data outside of the loop aswell:
companyinfo="<br><br>"&foretagsnamn&"<br>" &_ 
 adress&"<br>" &_ 
 postnr&"<br>" &_ 
 postadress&"<br>" &_ 
 "<a href=mailto:"&email&" style='text-decoration:none;color:#6d6d72;' target='_blank'>"&email&"</a><br>" &_
 "<a href="&kartlank&" target='_blank' style='text-decoration:none;color:#F90;'>Se karta</a><br>" &_ 
 "Du kan nu h&auml;mta dina varor: <span style='color:#F90;'>"& hamtatext &"</span><br><br>"
   response.write companyinfo&"<br />"
```

Hope it helps.